# I can't add foriegn key to my existing table. | sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, cs50

So i am trying to complete [finance](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/9/finance/). Following is the .schema:

```
    sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, hash TEXT NOT NULL, cash NUMERIC NOT NULL DEFAULT 10000.00);
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);
CREATE TABLE history(
symbol TEXT, name TEXT, shares INTEGER, price NUMERIC, time DATETIME
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX username ON users (username);
```

When i try to add foriegn key to `history` table it always return error. Here is my code:

```
    sqlite> ALTER TABLE history ADD COLUMN id INT;
sqlite> ALTER TABLE history ADD FOREIGN KEY(id) REFRENCES users(id);
Parse error: near "FOREIGN": syntax error
  ALTER TABLE history ADD FOREIGN KEY(id) REFRENCES users(id);
                          ^--- error here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think based on what I see in the sqlite docs that the statement should be together with the ADD column:

```
ALTER TABLE history ADD COLUMN id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id);
```

But you please check me on this syntax! Another option is to take care of creating the constraint at the same time that you create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE history(
    symbol TEXT,
    name TEXT,
    shares INTEGER,
    price NUMERIC,
    time DATETIME,
    id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES users (id));
```

It might not be something you have realized (yet) but every database has its unique flavor of SQL, so despite there being a SQL standard there are often little differences in the syntax of SQL for specific db implementations. So you always have to beware of this when looking up commands for your sql db.

Further detail on Sqlite foreign key constraints can be found here:
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-foreign-key/

Comment: Do i have to use this after creating the column id or before it.  Either way i get following error:                                                                                                      
             `sqlite> ALTER TABLE history ADD COLUMN id INT REFRENCES users(id);
Parse error: near "id": syntax error
  R TABLE history ADD COLUMN id INT REFRENCES users(id);
                                      error here ---^`

Comment: I fixed a spelling error where I had REFRENCES instead of REFERENCES. Hopefully that was all ... it works for me.